# How to set progress bar on AjaxUpload?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, ajaxuploader

```
new AjaxUpload($('input.partupload'), {
    autoSubmit: true,
    action: '/Home/UploadFile',
    onComplete: function (file) {
        alert("complate")  
    }
});
```

I used AjaxUpload for upload the file, and want to set progress bar on it. I can't find solution in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never run into AjaxUpload, but it doesn't appear to be documented very well.  I also noticed that it uses silverlight to generate the progress bar - are you expecting everyone who uses your app to have silverlight?

If you're looking for a component that pretty much does the same thing and has some wide spread support, I would suggest using uploadify:

http://www.uploadify.com/

It's pretty well documented, and gives you a little more script control than AjaxUpload.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll figure out.